# find character index in a string element of doubly linked list without using classes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm writing a script of some useful functions to edit doubly linked lists, and I'm not using OOP. So no classes are used.

Here is a sample of a doubly linked list:

```
dll = ['So true', ['^very much', ['try it', ['Not yet', None, [...]], [...]], [...]], None]
```

Note that the structure of the ddl elements is like: [string, pointer to previous node, pointer to next node]

I'm trying to create a variable that has the value of the character `'^'` in the doubly linked list as the "cursor" (just a virtual cursor, but it's really just an index of `'^'` character), without using classes (a function, or couple functions maybe?).
Now the "cursor" variable is a pointer to the node (containing the current string) and the position within that string.

The reason I want to create it is to use it for creating useful functions like: moving cursor one character to the left, moving the cursor to the beginning of the line,...etc.

cursor = index of '^' in doubly linked list with strings.

So my question is: how to find the index of a character in a string in doubly linked list without using classes?

Answer (score 1):

To merely find the position of the `^` character, you could use a simple recursive function to concatenate all strings (I assume all strings are at position 0 in the nested lists):

```
def join_nested_strings(list):
    if list[1]:
        return list[0] + join_nested_strings(list[1])
    else:
        return list[0]
```

and then simply find the index with `print(join_nested_strings(dll).index("^"))`.

**EDIT:**

If you want the result in the form of a tuple (string, index), the recursive function would look like this:

```
def cursor(list):
    if "^" in list[0]:
        return list[0], list[0].index("^")
    else:
        return cursor(list[1])
```

Please note that this simple function will raise an error if the cursor character is not contained in any of the strings.

Comment: The "cursor" variable is a pointer to the node (containing the current string) and the position within that string. The "cursor" character can be anywhere in any string in the doubly linked list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, here is the function that creates the double linked list out of a list of elements.
Let's say we have a list of string elements:

```
testList =['A lot', 'Very ^much', 'Try it', 'Nop']
```

Now to build the doubly linked list out of the `testList` we do it as follows:

```
# Build node function
def getNode(data):
    return [data, None, None]

# Build the doubly linked list
def construct_double_list(testList):
    nxt, prvs = 1, 2
    start, end = None, None
    for line in testList:
        next_node = getNode(line)
        if start is not None:
            end[nxt] = next_node
            next_node[prvs] = end
            end = next_node
        else:
            start = next_node
            end = next_node
    return start, end
```

If you run the function builder above, the doubly linked list(iterable both ways), would be:

```
dll = dll = ['A lot', ['Very ^much', ['Try it', ['Nop', None, [...]], [...]], [...]], None]
```

I already did that yesterday, but this morning I got stuck trying to solve the cursor problem. After some time I got it to work just now (finally!). Here is the function that creates a cursor as a pointer to the node (containing the current line) and the position within that line as follows:

```
def cursor():
    cursor = (None, None)
    start, end = construct_double_list(testList)
    node = start
    while node is not None:
        line = node[0]
        if '^' in line:
            pointer1 = node
            pointer2 = line.index('^')
        node = node[1]
    cursor = (pointer1, pointer2)
    return cursor
```

If you print the `cursor()` function above:

```
print(cursor())
```

You get:

```
(['Very ^much', ['Try it', ['Nop', None, [...]], [...]], ['A lot', [...], None]], 5)
# Node 1 and string index 5
```

Now I can create some useful functions to edit data, modify, add, delete, swap elements, swap characters within string elements of doubly linked list, ...etc.

Comment: That tuple consists merely of a string and a number. The string does not actually point to or reference a node. It might be a good idea to rewrite the code so that `cursor()` really returns a node reference. That way, you could easily access previous node via `cursor()[0][2]` and next node via `cursor()[0][1]`.